# Google Sheet Slug Extraction

Tags: xml, google-sheets, slug, data-extraction

Good day,

I do not know if this is possible, but is it possible to extraxt a slug from a url to display in Google Sheets/Wxcel. Basically. I am using IMPORTXML to pull title, h1 and meta description data, but also need the slug. When you have a URL:

https://example.com/this-is-my-slug

I would like to pull out the last part and display it on its own cell to just this:

this-is-my-slug

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

I have tried finding some answers on google, but the searches was not successful, also tried some other code snippets that I made some small edits to, but they did not do what I wanted, the snippets was for removing certain characters, not extracting a certain part.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I’d also recommend adhering to the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines in order for your questions to be properly answered by the community.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[^/]+$")`

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.